# Why array is not printing even after calling viewArray function?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, dynamic-arrays

As you can see in the code I am trying to print the items for the array by calling the `viewArray` function but it is not printing after the call. I tried to double the capacity of the array by using the `doubleArray` function and I also tried to halve the size of the Array using `halfArray` function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct DynamicArray
{
    int capacity;
    int lastIndex;
    int *ptr;
};

struct DynamicArray *createArray(int cap)
{
    struct DynamicArray *arr;
    arr=(struct DynamicArray*)malloc(sizeof(struct DynamicArray));
    arr->ptr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*cap);
    arr->capacity=cap;
    arr->lastIndex=-1;
    return arr;
};
// Function to double the capacity of array
void doubleArray(struct DynamicArray *arr)
{
    int *temp;
    temp=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*arr->capacity*2);
    for(int i=0; i<=arr->lastIndex; i++)
        temp[i]=arr->ptr[i];
    free(arr->ptr);
    arr->ptr=temp;
    arr->capacity*=2;
}
// Function to half the size of an Array
void halfArray(struct DynamicArray *arr)
{
    int *temp;
    temp=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*arr->capacity/2);
    for(int i=0; i<=arr->lastIndex; i++)
        temp[i]=arr->ptr[i];
    free(arr->ptr);
    arr->ptr=temp;
    arr->capacity/=2;
}
//Function to append an element in Array
void append(struct DynamicArray *arr,int data)
{
    if(arr->lastIndex+1>arr->capacity)
    {
        doubleArray(arr);
    }
    arr->ptr[arr->lastIndex+1]=data;
    arr->lastIndex+=1;
}
// Function to insert an element in array
void insert(struct DynamicArray *arr,int pos,int data)
{
    if(pos<0 || pos>arr->lastIndex+1)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid Index!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(arr->lastIndex+1>arr->capacity)
        {
            doubleArray(arr);
        }
        for(int i=arr->lastIndex; i>=pos; i--)
            {
                arr->ptr[i+1]=arr->ptr[i];
            }
            arr->ptr[pos]=data;
            arr->lastIndex+=1;
}

// Function to delete an element from an array
void delete(struct DynamicArray *arr,int pos)
{
    if(pos<0 || pos>arr->lastIndex+1)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid Index\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if(count(arr)<=arr->capacity/2)
        {
            halfArray(arr);
        }
             for(int i=pos; i<arr->lastIndex; i++)
            {
                arr->ptr[i]=arr->ptr[i+1];
            }
            arr->lastIndex-=1;
}

// Function to print the Array elements
void viewArray(struct DynamicArray *arr)
{
    for(int i=0; i<=arr->lastIndex; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d\t",arr->ptr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    struct DynamicArray *arr;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("1:-  Create an Array\n");
        printf("2:-  Append an Element in an Array\n");
        printf("3:-  Insert an Element in an Array\n");
        printf("4:-  Delete an Element in an Array\n");
        printf("5:-  View Array\n");

        printf("\nEnter your Choice:-\t");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            arr=createArray(10);
            printf("\nArray Created successfully!!\n\n");
            break;

        case 2:
            append(arr,99);
            append(arr,45);
            append(arr,67);
            append(arr,21);
            append(arr,32);
            printf("\nElement append successfully!!\n\n");
            break;

        case 3:
            insert(arr,2,89);
            break;

        
        case 4:
            delete(arr,2);
            printf("\nElement deleted successfully!!\n\n");
            break;

        case 5:
            viewArray(arr);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Too much code. Please reduce it to a [mre]. For example, remove the delete, count, get and search functions if they are not needed to reproduce the problem. Also, please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: append does not increase lastIndex, and fails to add the new value in most cases

Comment: In fact, it only appends if doubling of the array occurs.

Comment: OK, so I see your edit, but this isn't an interactive debug session.  Just fix your append method.  I assume you want to always append your new item, even if the array does not double in size, so why is your append step *inside* of your `if` statement?

Comment: your current edit only appends when it increases capacity

Comment: your 2nd edit has mismatched parens and repeats code unnecessarily

Comment: I fixed your append method.  Have a look at it now.

Comment: @Robert I think this IS an interactive debugging session.

Comment: @stark: I'm the only one who voted to close, so.

Comment: Note: you should not write a big pile of code and then find out it doesn't work. Test each function as you write it. You can do this easily with gdb and printf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with problems in the structure. You should not use `int` to index the array. You should use unsigned type for that. What's more I think that the `lastIndex` is a bad idea - use the size of the array, it is always equal to `lastIndex + 1`, so you will avoid a lot of adding later in the code.

The first function: `createArray`. You do not check whether `malloc` returned NULL. What's more your way of calling it is not the best. [It's not wrong, but I highly recommend reading this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Now, the second function: 'doubleArray'. Have you heard of 'realloc'? You should use it here. The same problem in the the 'halfArray' function.

About append: I am pretty sure that the condition in the if clause is incorrect. It should be >= not >. It would be more obvious if you used `size` instead of `lastIndex`.

Insert: You should print errors to stderr with `fprintf(stderr, error_message);` What's more, the same error in if clause.
Delete: The same as insert and I think you should halve the array AFTER you move everything.

After considering everything, the code below should work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct DynamicArray
{
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    int *ptr;
};

struct DynamicArray *createArray(size_t cap)
{
    struct DynamicArray *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr);
    if (arr) {
        arr->ptr = calloc(cap, sizeof(*arr->ptr));
        if (arr->ptr) {
            arr->capacity = cap;
            arr->size = 0;
        } else {
            free(arr);
        }
    }
    return arr;
};
// Function to double the capacity of array
void doubleArray(struct DynamicArray *arr)
{
    int *temp = realloc(arr->ptr, sizeof(*arr->ptr) * (arr->capacity * 2));
    if (temp) {
        arr->ptr = temp;
        arr->capacity *= 2;
    } else {
        // You should make it possible to return failure.
    }
}
// Function to half the size of an Array
void halfArray(struct DynamicArray *arr)
{
    int *temp = realloc(arr->ptr, sizeof(*arr->ptr) * (arr->capacity / 2));
    if (temp) {
        arr->ptr = temp;
        arr->capacity /= 2;
    } else {
        // You should make it possible to return failure.
    }
}
//Function to append an element in Array
void append(struct DynamicArray *arr,int data)
{
    if(arr->size >= arr->capacity)
    {
        doubleArray(arr);
    }
    arr->ptr[arr->size] = data;
    ++arr->size;
}
// Function to insert an element in array
void insert(struct DynamicArray *arr, size_t pos, int data)
{
    if (pos > arr->size)
    {
        // Errors should be reported to stderr
        fprintf(stderr, "\nInvalid Index!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (arr->size >= arr->capacity)
        {
            doubleArray(arr);
        }
        for (size_t i = arr->size; i > pos; --i)
        {
            arr->ptr[i] = arr->ptr[i - 1];
        }
        arr->ptr[pos]=data;
                ++arr->size;
        }
}

// Function to delete an element from an array
void delete(struct DynamicArray *arr, size_t pos)
{
    if(pos > arr->size)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nInvalid Index\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // I do not know what "count" is.
        // And I think you should halve an array after moving data.
        /*if(count(arr)<=arr->capacity/2)
        {
            halfArray(arr);
        }*/
        arr->size -= 1;
        for (size_t i = pos; i < arr->size; ++i)
        {
            arr->ptr[i] = arr->ptr[i+1];
        }
        }
}

// Function to print the Array elements
void viewArray(struct DynamicArray *arr)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < arr->size; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d\t",arr->ptr[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    struct DynamicArray *arr;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("1:-  Create an Array\n");
        printf("2:-  Append an Element in an Array\n");
        printf("3:-  Insert an Element in an Array\n");
        printf("4:-  Delete an Element in an Array\n");
        printf("5:-  View Array\n");

        printf("\nEnter your Choice:-\t");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            arr=createArray(10);
            printf("\nArray Created successfully!!\n\n");
            break;

        case 2:
            append(arr,99);
            append(arr,45);
            append(arr,67);
            append(arr,21);
            append(arr,32);
            printf("\nElement append successfully!!\n\n");
            break;

        case 3:
            insert(arr,2,89);
            break;

        
        case 4:
            delete(arr,2);
            printf("\nElement deleted successfully!!\n\n");
            break;

        case 5:
            viewArray(arr);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```